# How to populate all possible combination of values in columns, using Spark/normal SQL

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario, where my original dataset looks like below

Data:

```
Country,Commodity,Year,Type,Amount
US,Vegetable,2010,Harvested,2.44
US,Vegetable,2010,Yield,15.8
US,Vegetable,2010,Production,6.48
US,Vegetable,2011,Harvested,6
US,Vegetable,2011,Yield,18
US,Vegetable,2011,Production,3
Argentina,Vegetable,2010,Harvested,15.2
Argentina,Vegetable,2010,Yield,40.5
Argentina,Vegetable,2010,Production,2.66
Argentina,Vegetable,2011,Harvested,15.2
Argentina,Vegetable,2011,Yield,40.5
Argentina,Vegetable,2011,Production,2.66
Bhutan,Vegetable,2010,Harvested,7
Bhutan,Vegetable,2010,Yield,35
Bhutan,Vegetable,2010,Production,5
Bhutan,Vegetable,2011,Harvested,2
Bhutan,Vegetable,2011,Yield,6
Bhutan,Vegetable,2011,Production,3
```

Image of the above csv:

[image: Sample source data]

Now there is a very small country lookup table which has all possible countries the source data can come with, listed. PFB:

[image: Country lookup table]

I want to have the output data's number of columns always fixed (this is to ensure the reporting/visualization tool doesn't get dynamic number columns with every day's new source data ingestions depending on the varying distinct number of countries present).

So, I've to somehow join the source data with the **country_lookup** csv and populate all those columns with default value as F. Every country column would be binary with T or F being the possible values.

The original dataset from the above has to be converted into below:

Data (I've kept the Amount field unsolved for column Type having **Derived Yield** as is, rather than calculating them below for a better understanding and for you to match with the formulae):

```
Country,Commodity,Year,Type,Amount,US,Argentina,Bhutan,India,Nepal,Bangladesh
US,Vegetable,2010,Harvested,2.44,T,F,F,F,F,F
US,Vegetable,2010,Yield,15.8,T,F,F,F,F,F
US,Vegetable,2010,Production,6.48,T,F,F,F,F,F
US,Vegetable,2010,Derived Yield,(2.44+15.2)/(6.48+2.66),T,T,F,F,F,F
US,Vegetable,2010,Derived Yield,(2.44+7)/(6.48+5),T,F,T,F,F,F
US,Vegetable,2010,Derived Yield,(2.44+15.2+7)/(6.48+2.66+5),T,T,T,F,F,F
US,Vegetable,2011,Harvested,6,T,F,F,F,F,F
US,Vegetable,2011,Yield,18,T,F,F,F,F,F
US,Vegetable,2011,Production,3,T,F,F,F,F,F
US,Vegetable,2011,Derived Yield,(6+10)/(3+9),T,T,F,F,F,F
US,Vegetable,2011,Derived Yield,(6+2)/(3+3),T,F,T,F,F,F
US,Vegetable,2011,Derived Yield,(6+10+2)/(3+9+3),T,T,T,F,F,F
Argentina,Vegetable,2010,Harvested,15.2,F,T,F,F,F,F
Argentina,Vegetable,2010,Yield,40.5,F,T,F,F,F,F
Argentina,Vegetable,2010,Production,2.66,F,T,F,F,F,F
Argentina,Vegetable,2010,Derived Yield,(2.44+15.2)/(6.48+2.66),T,T,F,F,F,F
Argentina,Vegetable,2010,Derived Yield,(15.2+7)/(2.66+5),F,T,T,F,F,F
Argentina,Vegetable,2010,Derived Yield,(2.44+15.2+7)/(6.48+2.66+5),T,T,T,F,F,F
Argentina,Vegetable,2011,Harvested,10,F,T,F,F,F,F
Argentina,Vegetable,2011,Yield,90,F,T,F,F,F,F
Argentina,Vegetable,2011,Production,9,F,T,F,F,F,F
Argentina,Vegetable,2011,Derived Yield,(6+10)/(3+9),T,T,F,F,F,F
Argentina,Vegetable,2011,Derived Yield,(10+2)/(9+3),F,T,T,F,F,F
Argentina,Vegetable,2011,Derived Yield,(6+10+2)/(3+9+3),T,T,T,F,F,F
Bhutan,Vegetable,2010,Harvested,7,F,F,T,F,F,F
Bhutan,Vegetable,2010,Yield,35,F,F,T,F,F,F
Bhutan,Vegetable,2010,Production,5,F,F,T,F,F,F
Bhutan,Vegetable,2010,Derived Yield,(2.44+7)/(6.48+5),T,F,T,F,F,F
Bhutan,Vegetable,2010,Derived Yield,(15.2+7)/(2.66+5),F,T,T,F,F,F
Bhutan,Vegetable,2010,Derived Yield,(2.44+15.2+7)/(6.48+2.66+5),T,T,T,F,F,F
Bhutan,Vegetable,2011,Harvested,2,F,F,T,F,F,F
Bhutan,Vegetable,2011,Yield,6,F,F,T,F,F,F
Bhutan,Vegetable,2011,Production,3,F,F,T,F,F,F
Bhutan,Vegetable,2011,Derived Yield,(2.44+7)/(6.48+5),T,F,T,F,F,F
Bhutan,Vegetable,2011,Derived Yield,(10+2)/(9+3),F,T,T,F,F,F
Bhutan,Vegetable,2011,Derived Yield,(6+10+2)/(3+9+3),T,T,T,F,F,F
```

The image of the above expected output data for a structured look at it:

Part 1 -

[image: Part 1]

Part 2 -

[image: Part 2]

**Formulae for populating Amount Field for Derived Type:**

**Derived Amount** = Sum of Harvested of all countries with T (True) grouped by Year and Commodity columns **divided by** Sum of Production of all countries with T (True)grouped by Year and Commodity columns.

So, the target is to have a combination of all the countries from source and calculate the sum of respective Harvested and Production values which then has to be divided. The commodity can be more than one in the actual scenario for any given country, but that should not bother as the summation of amount happens on grouped commodity and year.

Note: The users in the frontend can select any combination of countries. The sole purpose of doing it in the backend rather than dynamically doing it in the frontend is because AWS QuickSight (our visualisation tool), even though can populate sum on selected column filters but doesn't yet support calculation on those derived summed fields. Hence, the entire calculation of all combination of countries has to be pre-populated (very naive approach) in order to make it available in report on dynamic users selection of countries.

Also if you've any better approach (than the above naive approach mentioned in note) to solve this problem, you are most welcome to guide me. I've also posted a question on the same problem without writing my expected approach for experts to show me the path on how we can solve this kind of a problem better than this naive approach. If you want to help solve it with some other technique, you're most welcome, [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61665275/guidance-needed-backend-sql-logic-for-dynamic-selection-of-a-field-by-users-in) to that question.

Any help shall be greatly acknowledged.

Comment: What is your database (SQL SERVER, Oracle, MySQL etc..) and what version? Solution will depend on the version of database you are using.

Comment: I believe the input is a file and you intent to transpose and populate to table?

Comment: Honestly speaking, I wish to do it in Spark dataframe SQL, which I think follows MySQL flavor. I can also do it using AWS Athena which is essentially built on Presto with ANSI SQL support. And am not going to populate it to any DB table, but just write a csv file back to AWS S3 and directly read from AWS Quicksight. Actual input csv file can have multiple countries, commodities and years.

Comment: I am not a spark expert, can do pivot in SQL if the data from the source file are loaded to a table.I guess some Spark expert would be able to advice better options.

Comment: This is quite interesting. Why don't you include all your requirements and upload some sample data (with different years and different commodities) for people to take a crack at? Off the top of my head, you will probably need to use [cube](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/sql/#cube) but your case is more complicated. It seems to be `n!` if I am not wrong

Comment: @VN'sCorner, you can write the SQL solution too, I'd try to convert it to Spark SQL or Athena query.

Comment: The question has been updated with clearer data and to the point ask. Hope this helps.

Comment: @LuckyGuess any help?

Comment: @VN'sCorner any help?