# Guidance needed: Backend SQL logic for dynamic selection of a field by users in frontend

Tags: sql, oracle, scala, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena

I have a dataset as follows:

```
Country,Commodity,Year,Type,Amount
US,Vegetable,2010,Harvested,2.44
US,Vegetable,2010,Yield,15.8
US,Vegetable,2010,Production,6.48
US,Vegetable,2011,Harvested,6
US,Vegetable,2011,Yield,18
US,Vegetable,2011,Production,3
Argentina,Vegetable,2010,Harvested,15.2
Argentina,Vegetable,2010,Yield,40.5
Argentina,Vegetable,2010,Production,2.66
Argentina,Vegetable,2011,Harvested,15.2
Argentina,Vegetable,2011,Yield,40.5
Argentina,Vegetable,2011,Production,2.66
Bhutan,Vegetable,2010,Harvested,7
Bhutan,Vegetable,2010,Yield,35
Bhutan,Vegetable,2010,Production,5
Bhutan,Vegetable,2011,Harvested,2
Bhutan,Vegetable,2011,Yield,6
Bhutan,Vegetable,2011,Production,3
```

**Given:**

1. If any one country has n number of years in the data, all other countries shall too have same n number years. Eg: If US has data for 2011 and 2012, then all other countries will have data for 2011 and 2012.

**Conditions:**

1. Aggregation only happens at multi-country selection. Grouping will be by Commodity and Year.

Eg: If a user in the frontend tool selects US and Argentina, we have to show -

**The Amount for Derived Yield = (Harvested of US + Harvested of Argentina)/(Production of US + Production of Argentina)**, i.e., (2.44+15.2)/(6.48+2.66), similarly for three countries it will be addition of three harvested value divided by addition of three production value and so on. That has to be populated in a new row.

**Note**: The users in the frontend can select any combination of countries. The sole purpose of doing it in the backend rather than dynamically doing it in the frontend is because AWS QuickSight (our visualisation tool), even though can populate sum on selected column filters but doesn't yet support calculation on those derived summed fields. Hence, the entire calculation of all combination of countries has to be pre-populated (very naive approach) in order to make it available in report.

Two of my question to all SQL experts is:

- How can I populate the rows of all combination of countries grouped by year and commodity so that it has data for all possible combination.
- Given that I could populate all combination of rows, how will the reporting tool understand which derived row to select depending on users choice of countries, as there is marking as to this row is US+Argentina that row is US+Bhutan, etc.

Any solution is extremely welcome.

SQL Tool preferred: Spark SQL or Athena SQL (runs on Presto) or HiveQL.
Less preferred: Oracle, PGSQL

**Note 2**: The sole purpose of posting this question, even though I've elaborated the same in another one is because I don't want to impose my naive approach on somebody trying to solve the problem, so here, I've defined the problem with more clarity than asking for help in solution. Whereas, in the other question I have given my approach for the expected result. In case if you want to see the other question, [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61643910/how-to-populate-all-possible-combination-of-values-in-columns-using-spark-norma).

Answer (score 0):

you can start with something like this:

```
select * from
(
    select c.Country, y.Year
    from
    (select distinct Country from table) as c,
    (select distinct Year from table) as y
) as cy
left join table as t on t.Country = cy.Country and t.Year = cy.Year
```

this will give you all rows with all combinations of Country/Year and optionally data from main table, so you can now add filter/grouping

Comment: I'm not trying to see the combination of years, for any combination of country the respective amounts should be aggregated by commodity and year.

Comment: Highlighting the formulae in the question.

Comment: @AakashBasu your first question is `How can I populate the rows of all combination of countries grouped by year` - I showed you how you can do it, based on this you can extend/add more grouppings/formulas

Comment: I think I have to run and see the result, shall get back to you with the result. If you wish, you can also go through the linked question at the bottom of this question, to dig deeper into the requirement.